# i want to select part of a string and insert it into database

Tags: arrays, string, codeigniter

I have output like the following below. From it I want to take only four columns of data, these are: ValueDate, Debit, Credit, and Balance. How can I select these columns with corresponding data from this entire string? (I am doing it in CodeIgniter)

```
string 'Branch:    cdd' (length=17)
    string 'DrawingPower:   5' (length=15)
    string 'InterestRate(%p.a.):    0' (length=22)

    string 'Balanceon1Aug2011:  "8,12,994.98"' (length=32)
        string 'StartDate:  01-Aug-11                       ' (length=26)
        string 'EndDate:    19-Aug-11                       ' (length=24)
        string 'TxnDate ValueDate   Description RefNo./ChequeNo.    BranchCode  Debit   Credit  Balance' (length=78)
        string '12-Aug-15   12-Aug-11   TOTRANSFER-vvvvvvvvvvvvJULY--   abdgfsdfhsgsdghfhfhfghsfghsghs  "12,300.00" 1,00,194.98' (length=125)
        string '17-Aug-15   17-Aug-11   BYTRANSFER-NEFT*jjhkhkhkhk*KERALACARSPVT--  uuuuehugreuhru  13,000.00   "1,13,194.98"' (length=135)
        string '18-Aug-15   18-Aug-11   TOTRANSFER-I98y
```

I want to insert the data into database like this:

```
value date       Debit            Credit            Balance
 12-Aug-15      12,300.00                           1,00,194.98
17-Aug-15                         13,000.00         1,13,194.98
 18-Aug-15       135.00                         1,13,059.98
```

Comment: Please discribe your Question

Comment: i want to select the field valuedate,debit,credit,balance from output string and i want to insert it into the database

Comment: paste your select Query

Comment: can you paste your output with print_r() . Not with var_dump